# Simple identity for entire function

Tags: complex-numbers

If $f(-\overline{z})=-f(\overline{z})$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and if $f$ is entire, then $f(-z)=-f(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Is it false when the condition that $f$ is entire is removed from the above statement?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with "entire " ! Take $w \in \mathbb C$ and let $z :=\overline{w}$. Then:

$$f(-z)=f(-\overline{w})=-f(\overline{w})=-f(z).$$

Comment: Thank you! There is a condition that seems unnecessary. I wondered whether it was a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

$f(-z)=-f(z)$ means that the graph of $f$ (for instance in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring)) looks the same if you turn it around $180^\circ$ about the origin (it has a $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry about the origin). $f(-\overline{z})=-f(\overline{z})$ means that if you mirror the graph of $f$ over the real axis, then the resulting graph has a $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry about the origin. It's quite clear intuitively that these two properties are equivalent.

Comment: Great! it is better understood intuitively. Thank you so much :)